# Multiple search by ID. Search not knowing full ID. Sapui5

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, sapui5, getelementbyid

I was wondering if there was any option to search an element by its id but not knowing the full ID, only part of it. So I could find an element without knowing its full ID or find multiple elements with similar IDs.

For example if I knew I had 3 objects with the followings ID:

"objectID1" "objectID2" and "objectID3".

Could I something like:

`getElementByID("objectID*")`

I have tried it in JavaScript using: `input[id*='PART_OF_ID_I_KNOW']`

But it returns an HTML object and I need it for SAPUI5.

Could I use something like: 
`var myControl = sap.ui.getCore().byId('myId');`

But not having to match the full ID (myID)? Thanks.

Comment: No idea about SAPUI5, but you've tagged this `jquery` and used a jquery selector in javascript, try it in jquery:  `$("input[id*='PART_OF_ID_I_KNOW']")`

Answer (score 2):

Though I would not recommend this but it's possible in a way as you describe it.You could look for elements with similar ID with jQuery, get the element's ID and pass it to sap.ui.getCore().byId();

```
var aElements = $("div[id*='PART_OF_ID_YOU_KNOW']");
//Lets say the first element returned is the one belonging to your control
var oControl = sap.ui.getCore().byId(aElements[0].id);  //If the element is a SAPUI5 control, you should get it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do this? Is it because you want to access controls (with prefixed IDs) inside your views and fragments? Did you give an ID of "myControl" to the control, but `sap.ui.getCore().byId("myControl")` doesn't work as the framework added a prefix to it?
If yes, the only reliable way to get a reference to your control is by using the framework provided methods in MVC views and controllers and in fragments.

**If you have a control called "myButton" in your view**, do `this.byId("myButton")` or `this.getView().byId("myButton")` from the controller to get a reference to your control.

**If you have a control called "myButton" in a fragment** that you embedded in your view via sap.ui.xmlfragment("", "myFragment.fragment.xml"), then use `sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("<prefix>", "myButton")` to access it.

Whatever you do, don't make assumptions on how the framework creates these prefixed IDs. These are not documented and can change.

Answer (score 0):

```
when you use `var myControl = sap.ui.getCore().byId('myId');`
```

it won't work.It is because when you try to get control by sap.ui.getCore() sapui5 automatically concat extra string to Your id eg`sap.ui.getCore().byId('xml0--myId')` and if you have provided viewId in manifest then while rendering control it uses that. eg
`sap.ui.getCore().byId('yourManifiestId--myId')`